# Custom taxonomy term links out of order

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have successfully listed the terms and sub-terms for my custom taxonomies, but the terms are out of order. With the current code, the list shows up as:

```
Category1
Category2
SubCat2
SubCategory1
SubSubCat2
SubSubCategory1
```

What am I missing to get them to show up like this:

```
Category1  
  SubCategory1  
    SubSubCatagory1  
Category2  
   SubCat2  
    SubSubCat2
```

My Code:

```
<?php  $args=array('public'   => true, '_builtin' => false); 
$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
    foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
        $count = count($terms);
        if ( $count > 0 ){
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $termlinks= get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);
                ?> <a href="<?php echo $termlinks; ?>">
                <?php echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>"; ?></a><?php
            }
        echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Hoping someone can help me out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) instead, which handles the display and ordering of hierarchical terms.

Despite its name suggesting that it's just for categories, it works with custom taxonomies too:

```
$taxonomy_args = array( 
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
); 
$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $taxonomy_args, $output, $operator ); 

if ( $taxonomies ) {
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        echo '<ul>';

        wp_list_categories( array (
            'order'    => 'ASC',
            'orderby'  => 'name',
            'title_li' => '',
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'show_option_none' => '',
        ) );

        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```